# Resize flyout window to appropriate dimensions with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, cross-browser

I have a "Launch" button that creates a new window containing a stateful web app.  I'd like to ideally adjust the window dimensions to exactly fit the dimensions of the outermost container (ie: no background shown by default).

The width is fixed via Bootstrap Responsive and @media.  The height is auto as-needed based on the inner elements in the container.  Ideally, I'd like to have the window size be dynamic for both however.

Now, the problems I'm having:

- I haven't figured out a combination of **height()**, **innerHeight()**, and/or **outerHeight()** that work.  To elaborate, they do give me the height of the container, but trying to use **window.resizeTo()** seems to account for the window's title bar, URL bar, etc...  basically, setting the height to the exact size of the container is not tall enough (produces a scrollbar).
- I'm having the same problem with creating the window.  I attempted to dynamically create the window of the appropriate width,height by passing it in on **window.open()**, but that as well doesn't account for non-page area.

I'm thinking a solution would be to figure out the displayable area of the window (available height after accounting for non-page area) -- however, I haven't found an elegant way of doing this.  Manually determining it and hard-coding would likely change on a per-browser basis, or even per-use in the case that they're using a different number of bookmark bars, etc...

I've also considered trying other approaches besides **window.resizeTo()**, but haven't found anything suitable presently.

Any ideas?

*I realize that setting a fixed height would be the easiest solution, but the height is variable at this point based on selected state.*

Comment: well some of the non page elements you can get rid of when opening the new window. So you can kill the address bar, status bar and etc. For the title bar you just have to add the static height for the title bar. if this only happens on IE then only do that for ie

Comment: I spawn the window with the following options: 'location=no,status=no,tilebar=no'.  However, I'm still unable to get rid of the location bar in Chrome 19 (haven't tested anything else yet).

Comment: well then maybe it is better not to use a new window. Since the behavior is not consistent, you can put the app in a modal instead